# Access Query Filter Not filter is excluding Blanks

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query where I want to exclude results where a certain field has a specific text value. However, I do not want to exclude blanks or other values.

This is what I did:
Field A
Critera: Not "Healthspan"

When I run this query, it successfully excludes Healthspan, but it also excludes all blank fields. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns only those rows where the condition, `[Field A] <> "Healthspan"`, is True. However, when `[Field A]` is Null, the condition is evaluated as Null, not True, so that row is excluded.

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| Field A      | <> "Healthspan" |
+--------------+-----------------+
| "Healthspan" | False           | 
+--------------+-----------------+
| "foo"        | True            |
+--------------+-----------------+
| Null         | Null            |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Add a second condition with `OR` to include those rows with Null `[Field A]` values:

```vb
SELECT y.*
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE
       y.[Field A] <> "Healthspan"
    OR y.[Field A] Is Null;
```

Comment: To encourage access to use indexes , you shoudl avoid putting the field as an arguement to a function.  so your first code is morelikely to run faster.

Comment: In retrospect, I think I should have stopped with just the first example query.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the IsNull() function.

```
Not "Healthspan" OR IsNull([tblTableName].[Field A])=True
```

You will find the IsNull() function very handy.

Comment: Just curious, is there a difference between using the formula above and putting 'Is Null' in the criteria for a field?

Comment: Yes, the IsNull() is a little slower since it is a function call.  The difference in speed is only noticeable if you have a large database.  A good benefit is that IsNull() is also usable in VBA code.  But best of all, if you have other complex criteria or function calls inside a SQL statement, IsNull() might be your only recourse inside those other functions.  However, in your case, "Is Null" is considered the best solution since it's native to the SQL code.  Just keep in mind that IsNull() can help save you from many other headaches that "Is Null" cannot.  Otherwise, they act the same.